# 'onListItemClick' method keeps Eclipse giving me errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, programming-languages

I'm reading Android Application Developement for Dummies and i'm at Chapter 9 where I'm writing a Task reminder app. I have a onListItemClick method, but Eclipse keeps giving errors....

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

    public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);




            String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin" };


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
            setListAdapter(adapter); 

            @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            }


        }
    }
```

my error: [my error](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/samplev.png/)

Eclipse says: 
"View cannot be resolved to a type"
"Syntax erroe on token ..... expected" (5x)
"void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick"

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

    public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);

            String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin" };

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
            setListAdapter(adapter); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the `onListItemClick` method inside the `onCreate` method. Move it outside of that method.

You are probably also missing import statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to override the `onListItemClick` method inside the `onCreate` method. You need to take that code outside the `onCreate()` method.